# How do I apply methods to a tippy.js instance from another file?

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, tippyjs

I am using `tippy.js` and `swiper.js`.

I am setting Tippy up as such:

```
tippy('.tippy', {
    allowHTML: true,
    theme: 'light div lg',
    offset: [0, 16],
});
```

This works fine.

However, I would like to close/hide tippy instances when a swiper.js has a `slideChange` event.

On my swiper init file I have:

```
 window['swiper_'+id].on('slideChange', function () {
    console.log('slide changed');
    const thisTippy = tippy($('.tippy'));

     thisTippy.hide();
 });
```

But of course this doesn't work.

Would anyone know how I could access the tippy instance from within the my swiper?

Comment: Does every slide have a `tippy` instance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to target that particular tooltip's instance. Something like this:

```js
const tippyInstance = tippy(".tippy", {
  allowHTML: true,
  theme: "light div lg",
  offset: [0, 16],
});

window["swiper_" + id].on("slideChange", function () {
  console.log("slide changed");

  tippyInstance.hide();
});
```

---

**Docs**

1. https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/tippy-instance/
2. https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/v6/methods/#hide

Answer (score 0):

The `slideChange` event exposes the `swiper` instance. With that instance you can get the current slide element. From there you can traverse the slide element and look for your tippy element.

Store the `tippy` instance in a variable to be able to close it whenever you get to the next slide.

```
let currentTippy = null;

window["swiper_" + id].on("slideChange", function (swiper) {
  if (currentTippy !== null) {
    currentTippy.hide();
  }

  const { slides, realIndex } = swiper;
  const currentSlide = slides[realIndex];
  const tippyEl = currentSlide.querySelector('.tippy');

  currentTippy = tippyEl === null ? null :
    tippy(tippyEl, {
      allowHTML: true,
      theme: 'light div lg',
      offset: [0, 16],
    });
});
```